# Spring security - what to do when Authentication is null

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring Security to manage authentication in my web app.
With it I manage the access to some object based on the name of the User.

So, in my DAO level I have this method which gives me the List of Park objects for the User

```
public List<Park> findParkByUser(int offset) {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();

        List<Park> parks = new ArrayList<Park>();
        try {
        if(auth != null){
            String name = auth.getName();
            User user = userService.findBySso(name);

        int userId = user.getId();
        Criteria criteria = createEntityCriteria();

            criteria.createAlias("users", "u");
            if(offset >= 0){
            criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("u.id", userId)).setFirstResult(offset).setMaxResults(elementsPerPage);
            }
            criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
            parks = (List<Park>) criteria.list();

        } else {

            logger.debug("Auth error");

        }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            logger.error("Auth error",e);

        }
        return parks;
    }
```

Now the problem is that when the session timeout or the cookie expire, I get a `null` auth. I would like to redirect the user to the login page, but I'm in the DAO level, not in the Controller. I thought I could get from the controller HttpServeletRequest and Response and using a custom logout manager

```
public void logout(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
        CookieClearingLogoutHandler cookieClearingLogoutHandler = new CookieClearingLogoutHandler(AbstractRememberMeServices.SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE_KEY);
        SecurityContextLogoutHandler securityContextLogoutHandler = new SecurityContextLogoutHandler();
        cookieClearingLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
        securityContextLogoutHandler.logout(request, response, null);
    }
```

Is this a correct way to operate or there is a better solution?

Thanks

Comment: If the authentication is `null` and you are able to get to that point, your security rules are flawed and basically anything else then configuring those rules correctly is nothing more then working around that instead of actually solving that.

Comment: Thanks @M. Denium, maybe I understood what was happening in my Spring Security Configuration

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the authentication and authorization is configured correctly, the `Authentication` object should not be `null`. Such a situation should be caught by the servlet filter (or whichever method you use for integrating Spring Security with your web-application environment).

If configured correctly, there are two possible situations:

1. Your application allows anonymous access. In this case, the corresponding filters will set an `Authentication` object that represents this anonymous authentication.
2. Your application does not allow anonymous access. In this case the filter should already catch the missing authentication and redirect the user to the login page. When using Java config, the details can be configured by providing an object derived from `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` in the application context.

Assuming you allow anonymous access, but certain actions require authentication, the correct way of dealing with this (if you cannot detect it on the controller level) is by having your model throw an `AccessDeniedException`. This exception can then be handled by an `ExceptionTranslationFilter` that can take care of redirecting to the login page.

Please refer to the [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.1.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#tech-intro-web-authentication) for detailed explanations about how to correctly setup the filters that are needed when using Spring Security in a web application.

Under no circumstances should you try accessing the `HttpServletRequest` or `HttpServletResponse` from your DAO. It violates the general contract that model code should not depend on the controller and makes the whole code harder to understand. For example, your DAO might later be used by different code (e.g. a webservice API, an application server, etc.) which handles authentication and authorization very differently and does not even have a HTTP request context. In this case, your DAO would not work correctly any longer. When only using the `Authentication` object and throwing an `AccessDeniedException` your DAO remains portable and can be used in any environment.

Comment: Thanks Sebastian Marsching, I thought i configured my Spring Security in a proper way, but now i understand it's not... I must understand what happens when session expires.. But it's otherwise correct to get the current user at DAO level `Authentication` to see what Park he can see?

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you want to make a query that selects data that is associated with a specific user. In my opinion, it is okay to use the Authentication object in the DAO, even though I would probably design it differently: I would rather add a user ID parameter to the DAO's method and implement the logic for finding that user ID in the controller. This way, the DAO stays flexible and can also be used to get the objects associated with a different user (e.g. for an administrator).

Comment: One more thing: I like to handle authorization as early as possible. If I can deny access on the controller level, I already do it there so that the request does not even make it to the DAO. So I would only handle authorization in the DAO, if I have to make authorization decisions on a per-object basis and cannot do it any earlier. On a side note: I like the declarative style offered by @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity because it makes it very obvious when some code may be accessed, but this is just a matter of taste I guess.